# Dart convert array of json objects to list of objects

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have array of country json objects like this

```
[{"id":4,"name":"Afghanistan","alpha2":"af","alpha3":"afg"},
        {"id":8,"name":"Albania","alpha2":"al","alpha3":"alb"},
        {"id":12,"name":"Algeria","alpha2":"dz","alpha3":"dza"},..
```

I have got them to a map like this

```
Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap;
jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
```

After this I have the data like this

```
[{id: 4, name: Afghanistan, alpha2: af, alpha3: afg}, {id: 8, name: Albania, alpha2: al, alpha3: alb}, ...
```

What i want to do is create a List of county objects from this

```
Country
{
int id;
String name;
String alpha2;
String alpha3;
}
```

Can anyone explain how to do this conversion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this straight forward way:

```
List<TestModel> myTestModel;
var response = await http.get("myTestUrl");

myTestModel=(json.decode(response.body) as List).map((i) =>
              TestModel.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

The link can be really helpful:
[json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable)

Comment: can you explain TestModel.fromJson method?

Comment: fromJson is a Function of json_annotation which is used in decoding the assosiated JSON value to the annotated field.

Comment: and TestModel is the same class as your Country class which has fields

Comment: and if you want to learn more about how to parse complex json you can have a look at this article. :) 
https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to make a PODO out of this,

```
class Country {
  int id;
  String name;
  String alpha2;
  String alpha3;

  Country({this.id, this.name, this.alpha2, this.alpha3});

  Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    alpha2 = json['alpha2'];
    alpha3 = json['alpha3'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['alpha2'] = this.alpha2;
    data['alpha3'] = this.alpha3;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Now using this you can access the fromJson method and also use the toJson method.